# how to extract a word before last in dot(.) delimited string in a hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to extract a word before last in hive table column, number of words in my string may vary but I just need a word before last.

example :
`1234.abc.tex -- > I need abc` 
 `gte.hjbkj.kjh.kjahd.ahskdhs --> I need kjahd`
 `adjnbsd.ajhsdj --> I need adjnbsd`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with some RegEx like this

```
([a-z]{0,}).[a-z]{0,}$
```

The $1 will have contain your needed text.